# I want to check what people do not join the baseball club?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are a group of students in the class, everyone can join more than one club, and can not join.

I want to check what people do not join the baseball club?

```
CREATE DATABASE `group` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `group`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `club` (
  `ClubID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ClubName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClubID`)
);

INSERT INTO `club` (`ClubID`, `ClubName`) VALUES
(1, 'Baseball'),    (2, 'Basketball'),    (3, 'Tennis'),    (4, 'Snooker'),    (5, 'Football'),    (6, 'Swim'),    (7, 'Badminton'),    (8, 'Dance');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ClubID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `StudentID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `member` (`id`, `ClubID`, `StudentID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),(2, 1, 5),(3, 1, 9),(4, 1, 18),(5, 2, 2),(6, 2, 4),(7, 2, 5),(8, 3, 3),(9, 3, 4),(10, 3, 6),(11, 3, 7),(12, 3, 8),(13, 3, 9),(14, 3, 10),(15, 3, 11),(16, 4, 11),(17, 4, 12),(18, 4, 13),(19, 4, 14),(20, 5, 2),(21, 5, 6),(22, 5, 8),(23, 5, 9),(24, 5, 10),(25, 5, 14),(26, 6, 1),(27, 6, 8),(28, 6, 14),(29, 7, 5),(30, 7, 6),(31, 7, 7),(32, 8, 11),(33, 8, 12);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `StudentID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StudentName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`)
);

INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `StudentName`) VALUES
(1, 'Mary'),    (2, 'Paul'),    (3, 'Andy'),    (4, 'Tony'),    (5, 'Jack'),    (6, 'Sandy'),    (7, 'Nacy'),    (8, 'Cherry'),    (9, 'Cathy'),    (10, 'Jenny'),    (11, 'Kelly'),    (12, 'Ash'),    (13, 'Rose'),    (14, 'Bruce'),    (15, 'David'),    (16, 'Harry'),    (17, 'William'),    (18, 'Richard');
```

All student:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PAmUA35G8FbFlxZGktamFsUkE/view

```
SELECT `Student`.StudentID, `Student`.StudentName, group_concat(distinct `Club`.`ClubName`) AS `ClubName`, group_concat(distinct `Club`.`ClubID`) AS ClubID FROM `Student` LEFT JOIN `Member` ON `Member`.`StudentID` = `Student`.`StudentID` LEFT JOIN `Club` ON `Member`.`ClubID` = `Club`.`ClubID` Group BY  `Student`.`StudentID`
```

Students IN Baseball Club (ClubID=1):

```
SELECT `Student`.StudentID, `Student`.StudentName, group_concat(distinct `Club`.`ClubName`) AS `ClubName`, group_concat(distinct `Club`.`ClubID`) AS ClubID FROM `Student` LEFT JOIN `Member` ON `Member`.`StudentID` = `Student`.`StudentID` LEFT JOIN `Club` ON `Member`.`ClubID` = `Club`.`ClubID` WHERE `Club`.`ClubID`='1' Group BY  `Student`.`StudentID`
```

Students Not IN Baseball Club ?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PAmUA35G8FRndRRmVWa3h4M1E/view?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clear write to write a query like that is `not exists` (better than `not in`, as jarl commented):

```
select  *
from    Students s
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Member m
        join    Club c
        on      c.ClubID = m.ClubID
        where   ClubName = 'Baseball'
                and s.StudentID = m.StudentID
        )
```

Comment: Or even better, advice people to do NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN. (The NULL thing you know...)